# Stop auto adding "///" in XML Doc Comments. (C#)

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, comments, documentation

How do I stop Visual Studio from automatically adding "///" in XML documentation comments when adding new lines.

For the following examples the '|' character stands for the cursor position.

For example when pressing enter at this line:

```
/// Some comment |
```

Is automatically enters "///" at the beginning of the next line:

```
/// Some comment
/// |
```

What I want is simply this:

```
/// Some comment
|
```

How do I make this happen?

Comment: You can press Shift+Enter

Comment: And if you pressed Enter by mistake, you can use Ctrl+Backspace to delete `///` at once

Comment: Thanks to both of you, but is there a way to completely remove this behavior?

Comment: You can disable "Generate XML documentation comments for ///" in Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Advanced -> Editor Help. That disables all xmldoc help, though.

Answer (score 0):

The triple slash pattern is a shortcut to invoke the VS XML documentation feature set. If you don't want that behavior, you could just use the more conventional double slash pattern; it won't produce automatic insertions on new lines.